# Incorrect wikipedia link to "Meek's method"

Tags: bug, election, broken-link

> After 4 days, the final voting results will be freely downloadable from this page forever, and we will calculate the winners using OpenSTV with the [Meek STV method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method#Meek.27s_method).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method#Meek.27s_method should be
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method#Meek

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just [fixed it](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Counting_Single_Transferable_Votes&diff=497918292&oldid=490611585) by adding an explicit anchor to the Wikipedia article, so that the old URL will lead to the correct section again.

I [also fixed](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Meek%27s_method&diff=497917545&oldid=17565910) the redirect from [Meek's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method) to [Counting Single Transferable Votes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_Single_Transferable_Votes) so that just linking to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method without any section anchor will lead to the correct section.

In fact, this is what we really should do: just link to the redirect and let the Wikipedians take care of it at their end.  (In particular, if anyone ever writes a stand-alone Wikipedia article on Meek's method, that's the URL where it'll go.)  However, with the section anchor workaround I implemented, this is not quite as urgent an issue.